# Firebase private key set as a config variable in Heroku not recognised - Django app

Tags: django, heroku, private

this is driving me mad. I have .env set up in my Django project and my firebase private key in the .env file. It works fine locally but when I move it to Heroku, set the config variable it does not recognise the key start -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----

I have tried loads of different solutions suggested on here, adding "", stringify the os.env variable but nothing works. Im bored now does anyone have an answer?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything special. How are you setting this value? Are you using `heroku config:set`? The graphical dashboard?

Comment: Yes I am. Error message back clearly states no begin

Comment: "Yes I am" doesn't answer my question. _Which_ method are you using? And what is the _full, exact_ error message? Please read [ask].

Comment: Yes I am using the graphical interface on heroku under settings and config var. The error I get back is: 

the data may be in an incorrect format, it may be encrypted with an unsupported algorithm, or it may be an unsupported key type (e.g. EC curves with explicit parameters).', [_OpenSSLErrorWithText(code=151584876, lib=9, reason=108, reason_text=b'error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line')])